# Cosmos DB: TOP vs OFFSET LIMIT

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm new to Cosmos DB. It's not clear from the documentation if there's any difference between the `TOP x` keyword and the `OFFSET 0 LIMIT x` clause in a plain (not having a `GROUP BY` clause) query?

From what I see results for these 2 queries are identical.

```sql
SELECT * FROM ROOT AS m ORDER BY m.id OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1
```

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ROOT AS m ORDER BY m.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it doesn't make any difference in terms of performance & cost. You can try out the two queries and measure the Request Charge. They are identical for various different combinations I tried, which is a good indication that they are treated identically:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't get clear description on it from ms document too. So I did a test.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting. Not sure execution time fluctuations tell anything though? I guess it may correlate with the load of the Cosmos cluster at that specific moment.

Comment: I haven't get any releated document on it. So any conclusion is based on guessing.  I'm not sure on it. And I think if you wanna create a  pagination, use 'limit' clause is ok.